# Ruby on Rails - simple_form_for how to show error for each field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, simple-form-for

I want to **display errors under my each fields**, my html.erb is the following :

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @municipality, @subdomain], :html => {:class => ''} do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :subdomain, hint: 'Dominio senza senza http://', error: true%>

    <%= f.input :subdomain_type, as: :select, collection: [['Sito','S'],['Api','A']] %>
    <%= f.input :active %>
    <%= f.input :draft,
                hint: 'Si applica ai siti e indica se il sito è una bozza interna (e quindi non deve essere raggiungibile dai motori di ricerca)',
                label: 'È una bozza' %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary', :value => 'Salva' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  admin_municipality_subdomains_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

in **@subdomain** variable I have "errors" property that return me the complete list of the errors, the question is : How can I display it under the subdomain field?

edit, **controller code** here :

```
class Admin::SubdomainsController < InheritedResources::Base
  layout 'admin'
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  before_filter :set_page_title
  load_and_authorize_resource
  actions :all, except: [:show]

  belongs_to :municipality
  add_breadcrumb Subdomain.model_name.human(:count => 2).titleize, :admin_municipality_subdomains_path

  def index
    @subdomain = Subdomain.new
    index!
  end

  def create
    create! {
      @municipality = Municipality.find(params[:municipality_id])
      admin_municipality_subdomains_path
    }
  end

  def destroy
    @municipality = Municipality.find(params[:municipality_id])
    @subdomain = Subdomain.find(params[:id])
    destroy!
  end

  private
  def permitted_params
    params.permit(:subdomain => [:active, :subdomain, :blocked, :subdomain_type, :draft])
  end

  def set_page_title
    @page_title = Subdomain.model_name.human(:count => 2).titleize
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just add something like

```
<%= @subdomain.errors if @subdomain.errors %>
```

under

```
 <%= f.input :subdomain, hint: 'Dominio senza senza http://', error: true%>
```

Comment: no I want to show the validation error... for example, for subdomain I have `validates :subdomain, :uniqueness => true` and i want to show the relative error.

Comment: @Leonardo hmm, I don't think I've ever had simple_form not displaying an error message if there is one. Maybe the problem is with `error: true` ? What is it for?

Comment: it was only an attempt, even without it error isn't display correctly.

Comment: @Leonardo check if `@subdomain.errors` actually has any errors, if there are none, my best guess is that you've messed something up in the controller. Could you provide the controller and the model code? It probably has something to do with the nested resources.

Comment: @subdomain.errors has erros! but i cant display it.
i've updated the question with the controller code.

Comment: @Leonardo well, if the errors are there, you can just print that specific error that you need with something like `@subdomain.errors[:subdomain]` or whatever the appropriate key (`:subdomain`) would be in your case. If it doesn't work, I don't really know, sorry I couldn't be more helpful.